# Placement of feedback line on DC DC converter, before or after cap? (and dropout problem with LT8390)

Tags: filter, dc-dc-converter, power-electronics, feedback

I am using an LT8390 DC to DC converter, I have a highly inductive load and it is causing dips. The dips are shown here (and about a 6V drop for 7ms):

[image]

I need to get rid of the dips, which I will increase the output capacitance from 100uF electrolytic to 1000uF.

The layout is such that I have moved the feedback line after the filter caps, thinking that this would keep the line more steady at the point I wanted it controlled at. I'm wondering if this could be part of my problem.

From a control stand point, where do I want to place the feedback line entry point in the circuit? 
Pictured below are the schematics, is A or B better?

Entry point A with feedback line before filter capacitors:
[image]

Entry point B with feedback line after filter capacitors:
[image]

Edit, here is the section of the board that has the feedback trace, I have ran it directly to the output of the board, instead of before the output cap.
[image]

Comment: Two questions:
What's the nature if the inductive load, is it transient, or dynamic (do the dips follow changes in its' state?
What is the length difference between the two feedback points?  from the schematic they appear to be electrically identical, but if there is significant length and current, then you could have some parasitic effects from the line length.

Comment: Also what node is channel 4 (green) measuring?

Comment: @isdi The green trace is the inductive load (motor) the yellow trace is Vout. I'll post a picture of the line

Comment: And the application note and PCB design example for  LT8390 says what?

Comment: @Ale..chenski says nothing specifically about placement, why do you think I asked? On linear regs it is better to place the FB as close to the load as possible.

Comment: from your captures, inductive(current) load & frequency of load you have not specified. But from dips, and with 100 uF, dips are due to sudden current demand of ~150mA. Unless this current demand frequency is too high this should be handled by output capacitors. Did you do any simulation in LTSpice with similar load?

Comment: The feedback path should be as short as possible. It is intended to stabilize the output, not to compensate for resistive loss in the traces or wires leading to the load. Since the regulator is switching at 100's of kHz, a drop of 7V lasting for ms is indicative of hitting a current limit or maybe a stability problem. In this case, I would not be looking at adding output capacitance. I would be trying to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: It dips 5V, slowly (10msec, right?), and then slowly goes back. I would say that your control circuit is extremely relaxed. I would start from massive feed forward- remove the Cflt completely, then maybe increase Cff. No need to wait for integrator to react to the dip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From their [reference schematics](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/eval-board-schematic/dc2457a-4-sch.pdf)

[image]

it is clearly seen that the feedback wire (R18) comes from the main filter cap C20, and not from the point of load. It is actually in between two caps, C19 and C20.

More, your entire layout has no resemblance with the [suggested demo board](http://www.linear.com/docs/56724):

[image]

All high-current loops in your layout have skinny traces instead of being solid rectangle of copper. I am afraid this is where your output ripple problem comes from.

Comment: And to be noted that reference design has 4 layers PCB. It could be also benefical to add an indutor cca. 800nH and an additional bank of capacitors, to isolate the load dynamics from voltage feedback sense

Comment: @MarkoBuršič, if a reference design has 4 layers, it very likely means that it is nearly impossible to make a good working converter in a two-layer PCB and meet advertised specifications. Otherwise the manufacturer's marketing would be more than happy to claim "low-cost 2-layer PCB" in the feature list for this product and expand its market.

Comment: My question is more along the lines of what is the difference between the two placements of the feedback line and how this affects the loop. What does this do to the feedback? It's a hard question, that's why I asked it here

Comment: The main body (inductor, fet, controller, bears a close resemblance to the reference diagram. I also have lower current. I would think it unwise to have to layout the reference board verbatim every time you did a new design.